# Create a variable that stores value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Can I create a variable in excel maybe by using macro or anything more simpler, which stores my value and then uses that going ahead in formula,

My main problem is, I am trying to make a formula for calculating Compound Interest monthly, so for Example: I invest Rs.2,00,000 @ 10% p.a interest rate.
In normal method I have to do:- 200000*(10%/12) which will give 1666.67, Now i will add (200000+1666.67)*(10%/12) which will give one value and so on. 
So i want to create something that can store the Principle amount and Interest each months.

Also i cannot use compounding formula since, lets say in first month i invested only for last 5 days of the month, then interest for first month will be calculated only for 5 months, and then computation of balance month will proceed.
Thanks in Advance. Do let me know if you want any more clarity.

Comment: you can store it as a name for example (from Excel 2010 (i think) it's Formulas tab, then Name Manager), no macros/vba needed

Comment: I can store a formula in define name, but then how can i use its changing values in my formula? Can you give me an example of what kind of formula you are suggesting me to use.?

Comment: I didn't suggesting storing formula in a defined name, because, as far as i understood your question, it is not what you asked for

Comment: Yes you got it right, its not storing formula what i asked for. So how are you suggesting i should go ahead with it? What i should store in Name manager?

Comment: You can also store single value as name and reference it in your formula (if, for whatever reasons, storing it in a cell is not an option for you) - this is what I suggested. In Name Manager, add name, call it "myVrbl" (or whatever you want to call it) and in the "Refers To" tab enter "=1666.67" (or whatever value you need this to be). Then use that name in your worksheet formula, i.e. "=A1*myVrbl"

Comment: That is the problem, if it would have been single value then no issues i could save it in a cell as well. But if you refer to my question again, when i will use 2,01,666.67(200000+1666.67) and calculate its interest of 1680.56(201666.67*(10%/12)) now for next step i need value as 203347.22 (201666.67+1680.56) and it will keep going like this by adding the interest to the principle value.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood the ask. Check out Chris' answer below. You can reference a cell (address) in a formula, i.e. If A1 has a value of 201666.67, you can write your "=201666.67*(10%/12)" formula as "=A1*(10%/12)" with the same result. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 2):

By far the simplest way of storing a static value in Excel, without using any VBA at all, is just to store that value in a single cell. That cell may then be referenced in any formula.

For example if you stored a static value in cell A1, you would reference that value in formulæ as `$A$1`.

If you don't want the static value on the same spreadsheet on which you're working, then you can create a new sheet named "Static" (or whatever you like) - then reference the cell as `Static!$A$1`. The sheet may then be hidden if you like.

You speak about adding principal amounts and compound interest. The easiest way to do this would be in a simple table, where the first row contains the initial calculation (including a reference to the static value as above); then subsequent rows reference the row above by means of formulæ. Therefore values would be added and multiplied according to a running total from the row above.

From your question, the specifics are not clear - so if you need more help than this, you'll have to give an example of what actual output you want - including several example rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create/use a `Named Range` in your formula. To create a `Named Range`:

> Formulas > Name Manager > New     (Or type name in **Name Box** as seen in below photo)

[image]

This will create a locked reference to a cell (or block of cells for other scenarios) that can be referenced in a formula *by name*. Make sure this cell has the value you want to reference of course.

---

For instance, if you name your range `Principal`, you can refer to the range (value) in a formula as such:

> = 2,000 * Principal

This is essentially the same solution as mentioned above, but it may be more intuitive to reference a named range (Principal) rather a locked cell such as ($A$1).